# Django loads save twice for any model

Tags: django, django-admin

After upgrading to Django 2 from Django 1.7.4, I face the following issue. In django admin save() method is called twice for any model in the project. When it comes to add new, it add the same entry twice, if edit it also saves twice, as a result admin result notification gives the same notice twice.If you click delete button, it first deletes and then gives notification that the entry does not exist, because it also calls delete function twice.

So far checked:

- settings file is loaded only once
- rewrote post_save

But no avail.

Settings

```
#SSL settings
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'dal',
'dal_select2',        
'django.contrib.auth',  
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.admin',
'compressor',
'mptt',
'django_mptt_admin',
-----
'myappA',
'myAppB',
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'myappA.middleware.AutoLogout',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution. The issue was in my middleware which was rewritten to Django 2, and request was called twice.